# Maximal inequality for a sequence of partial sums of independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory, independence, integral-inequality

Let $X_n$, $n=1,2,3,...$ be a sequence of independent (not necessarily identically distributed) random variables, let $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$. Prove the following maximal inequality: For all $t>0$,$$\mathbb{P}\left(\max_{1\leq i\leq n}|S_i|\geq t \right)\leq 3\max_{1\leq i\leq n}\mathbb{P}\left(|S_i|\geq\frac{t}{3} \right)$$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This inequality is known as *Etemadi's inequality*. Here is a proof:

For the disjoint sets $$A_j := \left\{ \max_{1 \leq k <j} |S_k| <3r, |S_j| \geq 3r \right\}, \qquad j=1,\ldots,n$$
we have $$ \left\{ \max_{1 \leq j \leq n} |S_j| \geq 3r \right\} = \bigcup_{j=1}^n A_j.$$
Consequently, by the independence of the random variables, $$\begin{align*}
        \mathbb{P}\left( \max_{1 \leq j \leq n} |S_j| \geq 3r \right)
        &\leq \mathbb{P}(|S_n| \geq r) + \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \mathbb{P}(A_j \cap \{|S_n|<r\}) \\
        &\leq \mathbb{P}(|S_n| \geq r) + \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \mathbb{P}(A_j) \mathbb{P}(|S_n-S_j|>2r) \\
        &\leq \mathbb{P}(|S_n| \geq r) + \max_{1 \leq j \leq n} \mathbb{P}(|S_n-S_j|>2r) \\
        &\leq 3 \max_{1 \leq j \leq n} \mathbb{P}(|S_j| \geq r).
    \end{align*}$$

Replacing $3r$ by $t$ finishes the proof.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment? Thanks...

Comment: Did you find this proof in Gut's book ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon Honestly I've never heard of Gut.. so, no, I didn't find it there.

Comment: @saz could you explain where the last inequality comes from? I basically asked that question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3704769/proving-etemadis-inequality

Comment: @MONODA43 Note that $$\{|S_n-S_j| > 2r\} \subseteq \{|S_n|>r\} \cup \{|S_j|>r\}$$ implies $$\mathbb{P}(|S_n-S_j|>2r) \leq \mathbb{P}(|S_n|>r)+\mathbb{P}(|S_j| >r) \leq 2 \sup_{i \leq n} \mathbb{P}(|S_i|>r).$$

Comment: Of course! Thanks!

Comment: Nice answer!  Btw, could you add an intermediate step $\mathbb{P}(A_j \cap \{|S_n|<r\}) \leq \mathbb{P}(A_j \cap \{|S_n-S_j|>2r\})$ to make it clearer?