# Proof of Levy's theorem without Ottaviani inequality

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, random-variables

Suppose $X_1,⋯,X_n$ are independent r.v.,

Let $S_n=X_1+⋯+X_n$, I am looking to show that convergence on $S_n$ in probability implies almost sure convergence by showing that $P(\sup_{m\geq 1}|S_m|>4\epsilon)\leq 4\sup_{m\geq 1} P(|S_m|>\epsilon)$.

I have been trying using Kolmogorov's maximal inequality but not much luck. Do I need to be looking at some martingale? Any hints?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/940147/

Comment: Thank you very much. That helps.

Comment: you are welcome. If you find the linked question/answer helpful, you can upvote it by clicking on the up arrow next to it.