# Convergence a.s. $\Longleftrightarrow$ Convergence in P

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

> Let $\{Y_n\}'s$ be independent r.v.'s, $S_n = \sum^n_{i=1}Y_i$,
>
> a. Prove that for arbitrary $\epsilon >0$, $$P\left(\sup_{\{k\geq1\}}|S_k|>4 \epsilon\right) \leq 4\sup_{\{k\geq1\}}P(|S_k|>\epsilon)$$ 
>   and for each integer $n$, $\epsilon >0$, 
>   $$P\left(\sup_{\{n\geq k\geq1\}}|S_k|>4 \epsilon\right) \leq 4\sup_{\{n\geq 
>    k\geq1\}}P(|S_k|>\epsilon).$$
>
> b. Use (a) to prove $\sum^{\infty}_{i=1}Y_i$ convergence in probability implies it convergence almost surely.

I am very confused about how to solve this question, by my intuition, convergence in probability dose not implies convergence almost surely.

Comment: For sums of independent random variables convergence in probability does imply a.s. convergence. The second inequality gives a.s. convergence easily by letting $n \to \infty$

Comment: Hi, Kavi@KaviRamaMurthy, could you please give me some details about how to get the first two inequality? Thank you!

Comment: Search for "Etemadi's inequality"

Comment: @saz, I know that Etemadi's inequality (a.k.a. Lévy–Ottaviani inequality) gives an inequality of the same kind with $2$'s replaced by $3$, but reducing them to $2$ seems very hard (or at least I haven't seen a proof of this).

Comment: What I know so far: With $U_n=\max_{k\leq n}|S_k|$, Lévy maximal inequality tells that$$P(U_n\geq\epsilon)\leq2P(|S_n|\geq\epsilon)$$when each $Y_n$ is *symmetric*, and Ottaviani's inequality gives$$P(U_n\geq2\epsilon)\leq2\max_{0\leq k\leq n}P(|S_n-S_k|\geq\epsilon).$$Also, Lévy-Ottaviani inequality tells$$P(U_n\geq3\epsilon)\leq3\max_{1\leq k\leq n}P(|S_k|\geq\epsilon)$$and it is known that the bound $3$ on the RHS can be reduced to $2$. But I failed to find any result with $2\epsilon$ in place of $3\epsilon$ in the literature.

Comment: @SangchulLee Yeah, that's right... I thought I had seen it somewhere with $2$'s but I can't find it right now. There is a version with a $3$ on the left-hand side and a $2$ on the right-hand side (https://eudml.org/doc/281295). For symmetric random variables the problem is somewhat easier, but it seems that the OP doesn't assume symmetry...

Comment: @saz, Seems like we are looking at the same paper :)

Comment: In light of the above discussion, @SarahWhite: are you certain of the statement you wrote? Are there assumptions you left out? (Since proving a. appears to be significantly harder than one would expect for an exercise)

Comment: Hi @SangchulLee, Thank you so much! I see the Etemadi's inequality,  But I still do not know how to reduce $3\epsilon$ to $2\epsilon$.

Comment: Hi @saz, the question dose not assume symmetry. And I make sure that the statement is right except for one condition that $Y_n$ is real valued r.v., but I think it dose not influence a lot.

Comment: @ClementC. I double check the statement, it is absolutely correct, and the only condition I did not mention is $Y_n$ is real valued r.v...

Comment: @SarahWhite, Despite of some literature hunting, I could not find any such result. And in fact, the paper which saz is referencing mentions that if $$P\left(\max_{1\leq k\leq n}\|S_k\|\geq L\epsilon\right)\leq K\max_{1\leq k\leq n}P(\|S_k\|\geq\epsilon)$$ holds for each $n\geq1$, for each $\epsilon > 0$ and for any independent random variables taking values in an arbitrary Banach space $B$, then $L\geq3$ and $K\geq2$. Although the problem above concerns only $\mathbb{R}$-valued, I suspect that either $L=2$ is impossible for $B=\mathbb{R}$ as well, or is possible but quite hard to show.

Comment: @SarahWhite Where is this exercise from?

Comment: Hi @SangchulLeem, I will keep searching any useful literature. Thank you very much!

Comment: @ClementC. It is from one exercise for advance probability theory class.

Comment: @SarahWhite In the meantime, do you know how to prove b). from a).? And, since the status of a). is unclear with these constants, how to prove b). from a). where all constants are 3 instead of 2? (and also in the meantime, check with your professor if they didn't forget forget, e.g. "symmetric", in the assumptions about the random variables)

Comment: @SangchulLee, Hi Lee, Thank you so much! I checked with my professor, he said it was his mistake. He changed the left side by 3 and right side by 2. But I am still confused about if we get the second inequality how to prove the first inequality? And how to use (a) to show convergence in probability implies convergence almost surely? Thanks again.

Comment: @ClementC. Thank you so much! Yes, I checked with my professor, he did a mistake, he replaced the right side with 3 and left side with 2. But he makes sure that in this way (a) can prove (b). But I am still finding the way how to show that.

Comment: @saz Thank you! I checked with the professor, he admitted he was wrong, then he replaced the right side with 3 and left side with 2. But I am still confused about how to use second inequality to show the first one, just take limit in both side and use measure Continuity? And how to use (a) to show (b). Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: @saz Thank you very much! I will revise the question! Appreciate for it.

Answer (score 3):

The second inequality is a direct consequence of Etemadi's inequality and you can find a proof, for instance, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/940147/36150). To derive the first inequality from the second we note that

$$\left\{ \sup_{k \geq 1} |S_k|>4 \epsilon \right\} = \bigcup_{n \geq 1} A_n$$

for

$$A_n := \left\{ \sup_{1 \leq k \leq n} |S_k|>4 \epsilon \right\}.$$

Since the sequence $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is increasing, the continuity of the measure $\mathbb{P}$ gives

$$\mathbb{P}(A) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(A_n).$$

Using the second inequality for $\mathbb{P}(A_n)$, the first inequality follows.

Regarding part (b): The key tool is the following characterization of almost sure convergence.

> A sequence $(S_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges almost surely if, and only if, for any $\epsilon>0$
>   $$\lim_{m \to \infty} \mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{n \geq m} |S_m-S_n|> \epsilon \right)=0.$$

If $(S_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges in probability, then we can choose for any $\epsilon>0$ and $\delta>0$ some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$\sup_{n \geq m} \mathbb{P}(|S_n-S_m|>\epsilon) \leq \delta$$

for all $m \geq N$. Applying the first inequality (for the sequence $\tilde{S}_n := S_n-S_m= \sum_{i=m+1}^n Y_i $) for fixed $m \geq N$, we get

$$\mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{n \geq m} |S_n-S_m|>4\epsilon \right) \leq 4 \sup_{m \geq n} \mathbb{P}(|S_n-S_m|>\epsilon) \leq 4\delta.$$

As $\delta>0$ is arbritrary, this shows

$$\lim_{m \to \infty} \mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{n \geq m} |S_m-S_n|> 4\epsilon \right)=0,$$

and hence almost sure convergence.

Comment: Thank you very much! For the characterization of almost sure convergence. Do you want to say "A sequence $(S_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges $\textbf{almost surely}$ if, and only if, for any \epsilon >0........"? @saz

Comment: By the way, why the inequality holds? $$\mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{n \geq m} |S_n-S_m|>4\epsilon \right) \leq 4 \sup_{n \geq m} \mathbb{P}(|S_n-S_m|>\epsilon) \leq 4\delta.$$ The question only assume independent not identically distributed. Does the inequality hold even if the sums does not start from $i=1$?

Comment: @SarahWhite Yes, that's what I meant, thank you. Regarding your 2nd comment:  The inequalities from the first part hold for any sequence of a random variables which can be written as a partial sum of **independent** random variables. For $\tilde{S}_n = S_n-S_m = \sum_{i=m+1}^n Y_i$ this is clearly the case; just write down what you get when applying the inequality to this sequence.