# Convergence for sums of independent r.v.'s.

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be independent r.v.'s (not necessary to assume identically distributed), and $S_n = \sum^{n}_{i=1}X_i$ for any $n \ge 1$. Also,
 $$P(\sup_{n\ge1}|S_n|>3\epsilon) \le 3\sup_{n\ge1}P(|S_n|>\epsilon)$$ is satisfied.

$\textbf{Prove that the series $\sum^{\infty}_{i=1}X_i$ converges in probability $\iff$ converges in almost surely.}$ (Hint: using the inequality above for $\Longrightarrow$)

To tackle this problem, I firstly to check the above is satisfied, I search some reference and online, I found the inequality is a little bit transformed by $\textbf{Etemadi's inequality}$ (which taking the limit in both side and using continuity). Some useful references can be found in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etemadi%27s_inequalityhte and PSQ [Maximal inequality for a sequence of partial sums of independent random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/940147/maximal-inequality-for-a-sequence-of-partial-sums-of-independent-random-variable).

It is easy to check $\Longleftarrow$.

Unfortunately, for checking $\Longrightarrow$, I am struggle in how to use the inequality to prove the problem. As what I have learned, I only know a.s. convergence implies convergence in P. In addition, if the sequence $Y_n$ converges in P, then there must exists a subsequence ${Y_{n_k}}$ converges a.s. But the problem mentions that converges in P implies converge a.s. I am a little bit shocking.

My try:
Suppose we $\sum^{\infty}_{i=1}X_i$ converges in probability, then I took limit in BHS for the inequality, that is .
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}P(\sup_{n\ge1}|S_n|>3\epsilon) \le \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}3\sup_{n\ge1}P(|S_n|>\epsilon)$$
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}P(\sup_{n\ge1}|S_n|>3\epsilon) \le 3\limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}P(|S_n|>\epsilon)$$
But how could I apply the condition $\sum^{\infty}_{i=1}X_i$ converges in probability. Do I need some additional steps to finish the proof? Could you give me some details.

Although I searched much information and got lots of helps from stackexchange mathematics perviously, but this is my first to post question here, I am very happy to join this amazing community :)

Thank U.

Comment: Are you in the same class as the author of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2758107/convergence-in-prob-implies-convergence-a-s ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon, Nope, haha, I don't know her, but her question is very similar as mine, interesting. Thank you so much for your link！

Comment: $$P(\sup_{n\ge1}|S_n|>3\epsilon) \le 3\sup_{n\ge1}P(|S_n|>\epsilon)$$ $\iff?$ $$\lim_{n \to \infty} P(\sup_{n \ge m \ge 1}|S_n|>3\epsilon) \le \lim_{n \to \infty} 3\sup_{n \ge m \ge 1}P(|S_n|>\epsilon)$$